# clipped text works in Chrome but not in IE9?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, css, google-chrome

I have a bit of code that works exactly as required in Chrome, but not in IE9.

My objective is to have a grid cell that clips it's text according to a maximum column width, does not wrap the text and shows the full text in a tooltip.
In internet explorer the cell does not clip, but is stretched far across the page, causing the need to scroll around.

The css I use is this:

```
.gridMaxWidth150
{
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The gridview column:

```
<asp:TemplateField 
    HeaderText="Comments" 
    ItemStyle-CssClass="gridMaxWidth150" 
    ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' 
            Tooltip='<%#: Bind("Comments") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to do this without altering the text at bind time if possible. I just can't understand why IE has a problem with it.
Mode and standard are IE9.

Edit: changed css according to Kinlan's post, still seeing this:

[image: comments column expanding]

It doesn't seem to respond to the 'max-width' when the 'white-space: nowrap' is on.
(if I uncheck the nowrap then it wraps the text and the width shrinks down to 150px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the `text-overflow` property. It's just that IE seems to have troubles keeping the widths on table cells down.

One solution is to wrap the label in a `div` in the table cell and apply the style to the div.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="gridMaxWidth150">
      <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' 
         Tooltip='<%#: Bind("Comments") %>' />
   </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/a72Va/) (not ASP.NET based of course, but it does show what the problem is).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think to try that...thank you Mr Lister, you've just saved my day from being a complete fail.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the values are:

`text-overflow: ellipsis | clip`

A value of `none` will not apply any clipping.  In theory you shouldn't need overflow.

Comment: Thanks Kinlan, I have adjusted my question to include what you posted.